# maven exclusions - if the dependent module removes excluded dependency module

Tags: maven

Consider

```
Project-B 
     Project-C
          Project-D
     Project-E
```

If Project A depends on Project B

Effective Dependency Tree for A is: B, C, D & E.

Now I want to excluded Project-D of Project-B out from Project-A

```
Project-A
     Project-B 
        <exclusions> <exclusion> Project-D <exclusion/> <exclusions/>
```

Effective Dependency Tree for A is: B, C & E

Now question is: In case Project-B decides that it will remove Project-D from its dependency like below

```
Project-B 
     Project-C
     Project-E
```

Will mentioning Project-D's exclusions of Project-B in my Project-A POM (where in first place Project-B doesn't have Project-D as dependency anymore) will cause any issue to my build?

I could create a dummy project with the above structure and analyse, however what I am seeking is, expertise advice in discovering any better option to handle this situation (if at all any exists any)

I also read this reference [Maven – Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) from Apache Maven (just to make sure I don't duplicate any question) but really didn't find any such use case in that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario the first thing is that you are trying to remove the dependency of Project-D in Project-A which will not work that way cause you can't exclude a transitive dependency in that way cause Project-D is a dependency of Project-C.

So the first thing you need to do is to make Project-C a direct dependency of your Project-A like the following:

```
Project-A
     Project-C
        <exclusions> <exclusion> Project-D <exclusion/> <exclusions/>
```

Furthermore the scenario you have described that Project-B decided to remove the Project-D dependency can happen. This would mean if you are depending on a transitive dependency (Things from Project-D) than you will get build errors.

That's the reason why you should always have a direct dependency on those things you are using...In other words using a class of Project-D that means having a direct dependency in your project-A to Project-D.